# Does this setup create time distortion?

Tags: comparator, time

You have an RC element. After the RC element there is a comparator. After a given time of X minutes(X * 60 = R * C), the comparator reacts. Does voltage drop lead to time distortion, provided that also the comparator is connected to the same power source?

Comment: Updated my answer with pretty pictures :-)

Comment: You seem to like the problem :-)

Comment: Well, I don't want you to believe just everything I say :-), so I wanted to *show* the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the threshold voltage for the comparator is also derived from that same power supply by means of a resistive voltage divider, then the time will be independent of the supply voltage.

But if by voltage drop you mean variations *during the X minutes period*, then yes, the timing will be influenced.

[image]

This graph shows the charging without disturbances in the power supply. The green curve is the output of the comparator.

[image]

The situation with a dip in the power supply. You can see that the time the comparator output toggles shifts to the right.

Comment: I am talking about a 9V battery losing charge in the long run. I want to know whether the measurements gathered when calibrating a rc element are usable in the long term or whether I needed to create a voltage stabilizer. According to what you wrote and what I presumed I can keep it that way, as voltage drop is small compared to X.

Comment: @Richart - Your RC time constant will probably be rather short compared to the battery's discharge curve, and then you can assume the voltage to be constant. An RC charging exponential isn't a good way to get accurate timings anyway: as you can see in the graphs a slight change in threshold level (the yellowish curve) may shift the trigger point far to the left or right. Maybe you could add more details about what you want to achieve, including accuracy, in the question.

Comment: not necessary....